# How to check if SQL Server database exists or not in C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and 2016 and VS 2015 to determine whether a database already exists or not. This code works fine if the database exists. But when there is no database found, it hangs for few seconds and then goes to the catch block. It prints out an error:

> Cannot open database \"ma14\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'Home\mim'.

My code:

```
public bool CheckDatabaseExists()
{
    string cmdText = $"select * from sys.Databases where Name = '{dataBaseName}'";

    bool databaseExist = false;

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
            {
                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

                if (result == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("database not found");
                    databaseExist = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("database exists");
                    databaseExist = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return databaseExist;
}
```

I found few already asked the same question. But the answer is not working for me. Or it does the same behavior. Like wait few seconds and throw an exception.

How to do it in a nicer way without waiting longer?

Comment: A log in error will not tell you if a database exists or not. You would need to make sure you have sufficient rights on the server to connect and make that query. You can reduce the time it takes to fail by adjusting the connection and/or command timeouts in the connection string but you are risking false failures if  you make them too low.

Comment: As I mentioned it is working fine when there is database exist. It means I have proper access right. But it hangs when no database found.

Comment: Does your connection string have a database set? Make sure it's set to `master`. If your users default database is set to the missing database, that could cause this behaviour.

Comment: What does you connectionstring look like. It's important that you connect to the ```master``` database. If your connectionstring is to the database you're checking for, the connection will fail.

Comment: Ha @Nick.McDermaid you beat me to it! :D

Comment: My connection string as:-  connectionString "Integrated Security=TRUE; User Id=HOME\\mim; Password=_SQLUSERPASSWORD_; Initial Catalog=ma15; Server=HOME\\MSSQLSERVER17;Integrated Security=TRUE; User Id=ES\\mim; Password=_SQLUSERPASSWORD_; Server=ESFIPC02\\MSSQLSERVER16"

Comment: @  Nick.McDermaid how to set to master ?

Comment: replace "ma15" with "master"

Comment: Remove Initial Catalog which is not needed in the connection string.  Especially if you do not know if the database is in the server.

Comment: My target database to check is ma15. I want to check is ma15 exist or not. If I replace it with master, then how can I check ma15?

Comment: Your select query does that doesn’t it? Also remove user is and pwd from your connection string. Please also edit your question and add it in there.

Comment: Thanks, everybody. I made the connection string as : connectionString= "Integrated Security=TRUE; Server=ESFIPC02\\MSSQLSERVER17". Then it is working like charm.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Keep in mind that omitting the default database only works because the user's default database is master. If it were setup as something else in SQL Server then you would have to change to master.